# Ubuntu 20.04 Location Services setting is grayed out in settings?

Tags: geolocation

I am traveling and am surprised to note that my recent upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 broke my automatic timezone switch feature completely. I did some research and installed 'chrony' package to get to at least manually switch to local time zone. However when I go in to settings and try to setup automatic time zone, it is grayed and states that both location services and internet access need to be enabled. When I go to location services setting, it is grayed out completely and I have no option to change.

I did some research and found some articles relating to change the setting in Firefox Mozilla browser, I tried doing that also but that didn't make any difference here.

I am curious what steps I need to take to enable "Location Services" option in my Ubuntu 20.04 install. - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image: Location Services window]

I found the answer after spending a good few hours for a problem that did not exist to begin with. It was simply a user error and a dumb one. I guess I am still not used to dark theme - the switch to turn on the Location Services is in the "Menu/Title bar" in the settings panel - I just noticed it right now accidentally while searching for something else all together.

Comment: Hey Naveen! Do accept your answer.