# 20.04 Location services is grayed out in Settings, how to turn it on?

Tags: geolocation

Location services is grayed out in Settings/Privacy/Location Services and there is no option to turn it on, or to choose which services to allow. I have not been able to find anything under Menu/Title bar in the Settings panel like the author of this post did ([Ubuntu 20.04 Location Services setting is grayed out in settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271321/ubuntu-20-04-location-services-setting-is-grayed-out-in-settings)).

Comment: can you not see the slider to the right of the words Location Services in the header bar? If the slider is set to the right services are on and if to the left they are off. Exactly as shown in your linked question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, THANK YOU 1 who made the comment!!!  There was a slider up there that was so light gray that I never saw it. It's now on. Thanks again!